# Performance: better to inizialize variable or just fill it?

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct, c++builder

Let's say i have a function that is called 10 times a second, something like:

```
void RxData(System::Byte *Data){}
```

in this function i want to fill a struct with *Data, where the struct is like:

```
Struct datastr{
float first;
float second;
}
```

in term of performances and memory use is better to declare a extern variable `datastr str1` and then doing:

```
void RxData(System::Byte *Data){str1=*reinterpret_cast<datastr*>(Data);}
```

or reinizializing every time the struct, like:

```
void RxData(System::Byte *Data){datastr str1; str1=*reinterpret_cast<datastr*>(Data);}
```

can someone explain what are the differencies in term of memory management? i tend to think that the second option is more "clean" but i cannot realy argue why.

Comment: Neither of those compile, and even if they did, they'd do different things...

Comment: not exactly a usefull comment, it seems to me that the question is not so obscure. Is it better to reinitialize the variable at every function call, or to declare it as extern? i may have done some coding error in the question, forgive me or try to fix them :)

Comment: No, *you* fix it. You claim to have two alternative ways of writing a piece of code and want to know which is better for style or performance. But I don't see that that's even the case. Come back when you have *two working pieces of code* that have the same observable behaviour, and then we can discuss which one is better.

Comment: Ok i read the faq and it seems to me that i did not violated the rules or the etiquette. Sorry to bother you so much KerreK SB.

Comment: If there's a right way and a wrong way, your wrong way is [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

Comment: @BiA: I'm really not bothered in the slightest. I just want to let you know that you probably won't be getting a lot out of this question the way it is currently written.

Comment: LOL, i don't know if Pauli sentence was about C++, anyway i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of memory management, the data will obviously be located in different places in memory. A global variable is placed in a static segment, while a local variable lives on the stack. Is it created every time? Yes. Does it affect performance? It depends. If `datastr` really looks like what you show here, then no.

It might have a slightly better performance even, because is very likely to be present in cache at the moment your function executes. A global variable might me there too, probably will, but its in a different memory location, so could mean the prefetcher will have more work to do.

Option 2 is clearly better in terms of style. Reader will have everything at hand while seeing the function and won't have to jump around to decipher the data flow.

Comment: @Fikitik actually `datastr` is a little more complex. It is a struc made of about 30 entries. Is the struct dimension something that can affect performance?

Comment: What I had in mind specifically was if the type is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure). Which basically boils down to if it doesn't have user-defined constructors, other OO style stuff like virtual functions and pointer-to-member data members, and all nontrivial data members are PODs too. The struct's size doesn't matter.

Comment: In the example i provided i intended `datastr ` as a POD. Anyway your point is interesting, if i add a costructor, something like: `struct  datastr{   
   explicit datastr(unsigned char* data)
  {
   *this = *reinterpret_cast<datastr*>(data);
  }
float first;
float second;
 }`
Does the situation change dramatically?

Comment: What you are doing with reinterpret cast is undefined for all types except PODs, according to C++ standard. However generally compilers are not so restrictive and what you show is usually fine. The thing I had in mind with constructors is that they insert code where you might not expect it if you are not careful. For example `datastr str; str = ...;` default-constructs str before the assignment. If you start using constructors, you might end up running more code than necessary. Using a copy constructor is much better here.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to version 2, it has better locality, better readability, and is less error prone. If the RxData is called 10 times per second, I would not even think about optimizing away initializing a datastr. But if you really care, then you can use the copy ctor for datastr and change your code to:

```
datastr str1(*reinterpret_cast<datastr*>(Data));
```

BTW, your syntax looks more like C# than like C++.

Comment: You don't have to write a copy ctor to enable this syntax. A default copy ctor works just fine.

Comment: @WernerHenze your btw is very interesting to me, in what sense it looks like C#? I have never coded in C#, and i'm trying to improve my C++

Comment: @BiA System::Byte looks like a .NET type, so I was mislead. Also "Struct" is not valid C++, it must be written lower case.

Comment: System::Byte is a .NET type, so, even if it'd be a valid C++ to define namespace System{ typedef unsigned char Byte;}, it's better not to do it.

Comment: Oh, and if you are writing in C++/CLI, you'd better tag your questions with C++/CLI, too. And it would be helpful to tell whether you use it in mixed or purely managed settings. Barely knowing C++/CLI, I'm not sure whether System::Byte * is an appropriate type for reinterpret_cast, while plain old standard C++ unsigned char * surely is.

Comment: @MikeTyukanov System::Byte is `typedef unsigned char Byte;` and it is not Microsoft C++ but Embarcadero